# How do i join two row in respect to date and time(hour and minute)

Tags: sql

I want join these row that date and time same but second are different. i use max function but it did not return me proper result.

```
|       DateandTime       |  t1  |  t2  |  t3  |  t4  |  t5  |  t6  |  t7  |
|-------------------------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
| 2019-08-06 15:44:04.000 | NULL | 0    | 29   | 20   | 150  | 20   | 20   |
| 2019-08-06 15:44:03.000 | 0    | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2019-08-06 15:43:04.000 | NULL | NULL | 29   | 20   | 150  | 20   | 20   |
| 2019-08-06 15:43:03.000 | 0    | 0    | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2019-08-06 15:42:04.000 | NULL | NULL | 29   | 20   | 150  | 20   | 20   |
| 2019-08-06 15:42:03.000 | 0    | 0    | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2019-08-06 15:41:04.000 | NULL | NULL | 29   | 20   | 150  | 20   | 20   |
| 2019-08-06 15:41:03.000 | 0    | 0    | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2019-08-06 15:40:04.000 | NULL | 0    | 29   | 20   | 150  | 20   | 20   |
| 2019-08-06 15:40:03.000 | 0    | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2019-08-06 15:39:04.000 | NULL | 0    | 29   | 20   | 150  | 20   | 20   |
| 2019-08-06 15:39:03.000 | 0    | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2019-08-06 15:38:04.000 | NULL | NULL | 29   | 20   | 150  | 20   | 20   |
| 2019-08-06 15:38:03.000 | 0    | 0    | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
```

Comment: Tag appropriate database name and please format your data so that they becomes readable.

Comment: Is that table data, current result or the wanted result? We need sample table data and the expected result. And also show us your current query attempt. Take a look at [mcve] too.

Comment: Assuming that sample data is your _input_, what exactly is the _result_ you are looking for?

Comment: it is sample data table

Comment: join that two row like
|       DateandTime             |  t1   |  t2  |  t3  |  t4  |  t5  |  t6  |  t7  |
|-----------------------            --|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
| 2019-08-06 15:44:04.000 | 0    | 0    | 29   | 20   | 150  | 20   | 20   |

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **MSSQL**, this following script will work. You can also use the same logic for other databases just applying appropriate DATETIME conversion for that database.

```
SELECT 
FORMAT(CAST(DateandTime AS DATETIME), 'dd-MM.yyyy HH:mm'),
-- You can also use SUM/AVG for all columns if both row can
-- have data and based on your requirement.
MAX(t1) T1, 
MAX(t2) T2,
MAX(t3) T3,
MAX(t4) T4,
MAX(t5) T5,
MAX(t6) T6,
MAX(t7) T7
FROM your_table
GROUP BY FORMAT(CAST(DateandTime AS DATETIME), 'dd-MM.yyyy HH:mm') 
-- Do not required CAST(DateandTime AS DATETIME) if your
-- DateandTime column type is already DATETIME
```